# FOSElasticaBundle / Custom filter

Tags: symfony, foselasticabundle

I have an entity with 
`title, url, description, text, enabled,...`
I want to search only through **enabled = true** articles.
How can I do it in elastica?

My config:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        appletrh:
            index_name: 'domain.com'
            client: default
            types:
                products:
                    properties:
                        title: { type: string, analyzer: czech }
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: Web\MagazineBundle\Entity\Article
                        elastica_to_model_transformer:
                          **query_builder_method: search**
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
                        finder: ~
```

EntityRepository **search** function

```
 public function search()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $qb->where('p.enabled = true');

        return $qb;
    }
```

Action:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request)
{
    $keyword = $request->query->get('keyword');
    $finder = $this->get('fos_elastica.finder.domain.articles');
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $articles= $finder->createPaginatorAdapter($keyword);
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate($articles, $request->query->get('page', 1), 12);


    return $this->render('WebMagazineBundle:Search:search.html.twig', ['articles' => $pagination]);
}
```

I thought that this is the right solution, but it's still returning all of the data from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like you should use "provider", not "elastica_to_model_transformer" option in the bundle config for that purpose, like:

```
provider:
   query_builder_method: search
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like there is a mistake in their documentation.